# add new Element to a specific part of xml tree

Tags: c#, xml

i need to add a new Element to a specific part of xml tree but i can't make it work.

this is my xml input

```
    <structMap LABEL="Logical Structure" TYPE="LOGICAL">
  <div ID="DIVL1" TYPE="CONTENT">
    <div ID="DIVL2" TYPE="" DMDID="MODSMD_ARTICLE1" LABEL="">
      <div ID="DIVL3">
        <div ID="DIVL31" TYPE="TITLE" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</structMap>
```

and here is my desired output

```
   <structMap LABEL="Logical Structure" TYPE="LOGICAL">
  <div ID="DIVL1" TYPE="CONTENT">
    <div ID="DIVL2" TYPE="" DMDID="MODSMD_ARTICLE1" LABEL="">
      <div ID="DIVL3">
        <div ID="DIVL31" TYPE="TITLE">
        <fptr>
          <area BETYPE="IDREF" FILEID="ALTO0011" BEGIN="P11_TB3"/>
        </fptr>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</structMap>
```

and here is my code

```
var b = dc.Descendants().Attributes("TYPE").Where(ee => ee.Value == "TITLE").First();
```

i don't have b.AddFist. how can i make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, of course, that you're using LINQ to XML, it's not surprising that you wouldn't have `b.AddFirst()`. `b` is an [XAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), not an [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx).

It looks like you're looking for `b.Parent.AddFirst()`.

Answer (score 1):

Usse xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement title = doc
               .Descendants("div")
               .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("TYPE") == "TITLE")
               .FirstOrDefault();

            title.Add(new XElement("fptr", new object[] {
               new XElement("area", new object[] {
                   new XAttribute("BETYPE","IDREF"),
                   new XAttribute("FILEID","ALTO0011"),
                   new XAttribute("BEGIN","P11_TB3")
               })
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `title.Add` could have null exception.  Use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault`.