# wpf treeview to xml

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, treeview

i followed the tutorial here: 
http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/treeview-data-binding-multiple-templates/

in order to populate my treeview

and here is the screenshot of the program.

[image]

in my program i need to create xml based from treeview

this is how to xml output should look like

```
<div TYPE="BODY_CONTENT">
   <div TYPE="PARAGRAPH" ORDER="1">
      <div TYPE="TEXT">
         <fptr>
           <area name="John Doe"/>
           <area name="Jane Doe"/> 
           <area name="Sammy Doe"/>
         </fptr>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div TYPE="PARAGRAPH" ORDER="2">
      <div TYPE="TEXT">
         <fptr>
           <area name="Mark Moe"/>
           <area name="Norma Moe"/> 
         </fptr>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

i know a little bit of how to create an xml(based from those who answer my questions here, i have ask a lot of xml related question) but i haven't experience how to create this kind of xml.

so far i only have the loop for the treeview

```
foreach (Family item in trvFamilies.Items)
            {  
                foreach (var itm in item.Members)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(itm.Name);
                }
            }
```

in the xml. the order is based from parent of the treeview

and the values inside fptr tags came from the child node of each parent node in the treeview

Answer (score 1):

You need to read more about how to create your own XML's, there is a lot of question's about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492705/how-to-create-xml-document-using-xmldocument)

As well would recommend to read about [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) and xmlDocument's method [CreateElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fw1ys7w6(v=vs.110).aspx) that's all you need to create custom Xml's.

Edit: Sorry forget about main source for any stuff about xml serialization: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90c86ass(v=vs.110).aspx) :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried two way binding shown in this link? [Two-way binding of Xml data to the WPF TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188001/two-way-binding-of-xml-data-to-the-wpf-treeview)
Make sure your question is clear

Answer (score 0):

a while ago i ask another question. ive been looking all over for some reference and then i read the comment of jdweng and it solve my problem,  here is the link

[add new Element to a specific part of xml tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819241/add-new-element-to-a-specific-part-of-xml-tree)

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("div", new XAttribute("TYPE", "BODY_CONTENT")));
            XElement title = doc
               .Descendants("div")
               .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("TYPE") == "BODY_CONTENT")
               .FirstOrDefault();
            int i = 1;
            foreach (Family item in trvFamilies.Items)
            {
                title.Add(new XElement("div",  new XAttribute("TYPE", "PARAGRAPH"), new XAttribute("ORDER", i.ToString())));
                XElement text = doc
                        .Descendants("div")
                        .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("ORDER") == i.ToString())
                    .FirstOrDefault();
                title.Add(new XElement("div", new XAttribute("TYPE", "TEXT"), new XElement("fptr", new  XAttribute("order", i.ToString()))));

                foreach (var itm in item.Members)
                {
                    XElement area = doc
                      .Descendants("fptr")
                      .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("order") == i.ToString())
                      .FirstOrDefault();
                    area.AddFirst(new XElement("area", new XAttribute("name", itm.Name)));
                }
                i++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(doc);
```